# Keep first row with two columns, the rest single columns wide with wrap for words

Tags: latex

I am trying to, keep two columns at the top row, and make the rest single column with automatic wide expansion. But, I don't know how to do it. I read in the documentation, but was too much details for me to comprehend.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{tblr}{width=\textwidth,
            colspec={X[l]  X[r]},
            hline{1,3} = {solid},
        }
        \text{Lorem Ipsum} & \text{Ipsum Lorem}\\
        It is easy with "tabularray" package to set row fonts. And you can change the environment from "tblr" to "longtblr" to get a long table. \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Current output:**

[image]

**Desired output:**

[image]

Comment: If you cross-post the same question on multiple sites, you should include links to all other versions of the question in every question. X-posting without explicit links has the risk of wasting both the time of users who might put time and effort into answering a post, which already has an answer elsewhere, as well as the time of users who might have the same problem but can't find the solutions you might have gotten on one of the other sites you x-posted your question

Comment: x-post https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/697859/36296

Comment: You must not use `\text{...}` outside of math mode, and even there you would need the `amsmath` package. What's your intention of using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\SetCell` to merge multiple cells:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{tblr}{width=\textwidth,
            colspec={X[l]  X[r]},
            hline{1,3} = {solid},
            cell{2-Z}{1} = {halign=j,wd=\linewidth-12pt}
        }
        \textit{Lorem Ipsum} & \textit{Ipsum Lorem}\\
        \SetCell[c=2]{} It is easy with "tabularray" package to set row fonts. And you can change the environment from "tblr" to "longtblr" to get a long table. &\\
        \SetCell[c=2]{} It is easy with "tabularray" package to set row fonts. And you can change the environment from "tblr" to "longtblr" to get a long table. &\\
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]